# Console Warning: "Notion Warning Reverting mutation of..." does this mean all mutations are now prevented?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contenteditable, mutation-observers, mutation

Here is the screenshot of the warning I am receiving while either;

- changing the contentEditable attribute of a node to "true" from "false"
- executing range.surroundContent(). Details of error will differ on this one, but the general note is the same.

via the chrome extension I am building.

[image: s/s of warning in console]

I couldn't find much info on the error posted, so I would like to know whether my understanding that any DOM manipulations that execute or require a mutation is now prevented by the site? Or is there a workaround for this as well please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/obahareth/notion-rtl/issues/28#issuecomment-998233268

Seems like Notion has been deploying a protection mechanism to prevent DOM manipulations via external scripts being embedded. Just leaving note.